# Javascript autocompletion plugin for VS. Net

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, autocomplete

I'm doing a lot of work in Javascript with Visual Studio .Net 2008.  It would be nice to have some sort of plugin to do auto completion for Javascript (a bit like ctrl space and a list of options come up in Java/C# etc).

Is there such plugin/tool out there?

Thanks.

Comment: Intellisense you mean? Isn't it built-in? There is also a jQuery add-on which you can install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

[Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBEE1648-7106-44A7-9649-6D9F6D58056E&displaylang=en)

I haven't tried it, but the VS2010 beta has even better Javascript Intellisense.